# Why does CAST(1 AS SIGNED INTEGER) return a BIGINT on MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

If I do `CAST(1 AS SIGNED INTEGER)` I always end up getting a `BIGINT` returned, for example:

```
$ mysql -u root -p --column-type-info
Enter password:

--- Copyright and help message snipped for brevity ---

mysql> select cast(1 as signed integer);
Field   1:  `cast(1 as signed integer)`
Catalog:    `def`
Database:   ``
Table:      ``
Org_table:  ``
Type:       LONGLONG            <== LONGLONG i.e. 64 bit integer
Collation:  binary (63)
Length:     1
Max_length: 1
Decimals:   0
Flags:      NOT_NULL BINARY NUM


+---------------------------+
| cast(1 as signed integer) |
+---------------------------+
|                         1 |
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I would have expected the return type from that cast to be a `LONG` (32 bit integer).

If I select a column from a table that has an `INT` I see that it is indeed just a `LONG`:

```
mysql> describe contact;

+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| contact_id | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |

      == remainder of table snipped ==

mysql> select contact_id from contact where contact_id = 20;
Field   1:  `contact_id`
Catalog:    `def`
Database:   `centreon`
Table:      `contact`
Org_table:  `contact`
Type:       LONG                     <== LONG i.e. 32 bit integer
Collation:  binary (63)
Length:     11
Max_length: 2
Decimals:   0
Flags:      NOT_NULL PRI_KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NUM PART_KEY


+------------+
| contact_id |
+------------+
|         20 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

If I cast the same column to a signed integer, I again get a 64 bit integer returned:

```
mysql> select CAST(contact_id as signed integer) from contact where contact_id = 20;
Field   1:  `CAST(contact_id as signed integer)`
Catalog:    `def`
Database:   ``
Table:      ``
Org_table:  ``
Type:       LONGLONG
Collation:  binary (63)
Length:     11
Max_length: 2
Decimals:   0
Flags:      NOT_NULL BINARY NUM


+------------------------------------+
| CAST(contact_id as signed integer) |
+------------------------------------+
|                                 20 |
+------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

There is a similarly reported issue here:

> http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=64084

But sadly the OP doesn't get a straight answer.

Is this a bug in the `CAST()` function or is this by design?

Comment: Looking at the docs for cast()/convert(), it only mentions 64-bit integers http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast

Comment: @Phil - I did read that over and over. Why does it say `SIGNED [INTEGER]` in the section *The type for the result can be one of the following values:*. Is a `SIGNED INTEGER` in the context of a `CAST` not in fact a 32 bit integer?

Comment: I was reading the "MySQL supports arithmetic with both signed and unsigned 64-bit values. If you are using numeric operators (such as + or -) and one of the operands is an unsigned integer, the result is unsigned by default (see Section 12.6.1, “Arithmetic Operators”). You can override this by using the SIGNED or UNSIGNED cast operator to cast a value to a signed or unsigned 64-bit integer, respectively." part

Comment: @Phil - yeah I read that too, and indeed that behaves as expected i.e. doing `SELECT 1+1` results in a `BIGINT`. But it still doesn't explain away why `CAST()` behaves contrary to the documentation (as I understand it) and produces a `BIGINT` even if asked to cast to `SIGNED INTEGER` or `UNSIGNED INTEGER` on a single scalar value.

Comment: The best solution I found here: [Convert BIGINT UNSIGNED to INT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11595217/convert-bigint-unsigned-to-int)

Comment: Did you get any solution for this ?

Comment: @trusha no I didn't and it's so long ago now, and I also flipped the bozo bit on MySQL as a sensible and sane database product.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see on https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_cast.asp

> SIGNED    Converts value to SIGNED (a signed 64-bit integer)
>
> UNSIGNED  Converts value to UNSIGNED (an unsigned 64-bit integer)

And from the official MySQL documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html

> MySQL supports arithmetic with both signed and unsigned 64-bit values. For numeric operators (such as + or -) where one of the operands is an unsigned integer, the result is unsigned by default (see Section 12.6.1, “Arithmetic Operators”). To override this, use the SIGNED or UNSIGNED cast operator to cast a value to a signed or unsigned 64-bit integer, respectively.

So looks like the CAST output will actually be a 64 bits integer when you use SIGNED or UNSIGNED datatypes.

Answer (score -1):

Int store as 32 bit in MySQL.

MySQL supports arithmetic with both signed and unsigned 64-bit values. For numeric operators (such as + or -) where one of the operands is an unsigned integer, the result is unsigned by default. To override this, use the SIGNED or UNSIGNED cast operator to cast a value to a signed or unsigned 64-bit integer, respectively.

That's why is for int it is showing long int : 32 bit

and for signed int it is showing long long int OR BIG int : 64 int